# How do I open the Account Settings for a specific Account?

Tags: android

I know that via the Account Manager I can access to the list of the accounts on the device.

```
 Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
```

I know as well that using the `android.settings.ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS` I can open the Sync Settings for a specific account

```
Intent in=new Intent("android.settings.ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS");
in.putExtra("account", accounts[3]);
```

---

What I would like to do is to open the "Account Settings" for a specific account, like this:

[image]

And *not* like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### General Approach:

The tricky part is that Android's definition of Account is pretty abstract, so depending on your use case you'll encounter accounts without these screens, or with multiple screens. These screens may not look like Preferences/Settings screens at all - they could be any Activity as defined by the `Account` authenticator.

Generally though, I think this is what you could do:

1. Use the `getAuthenticatorTypes()` method of `AccountManager`. This
   will give you all of the AuthenticatorDescriptions. Depending on
   your use case, you can pick the AuthenticatorDescription you care
   about (based on the "type" value) and just further investigate that.
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthenticatorTypes()
2. The `AuthenticatorDescription` will tell you the
   `accountPreferencesId` that defines the "hierarchy of
   PreferenceScreen to be added to the settings page for the account".
   Which in turn defines a "PreferenceScreen xml hierarchy that
   contains a list of PreferenceScreens that can be invoked to manage
   the authenticator".
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AuthenticatorDescription.html
3. Use the `accountPreferencesId` and the package provided by the
   `AuthenticatorDescription` to parse the `Intents` you need, allowing you
   to navigate your user to them. Reference for what the XML will look
   like:
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html

### tl;dr - the code:

Here's a method that finds the `Activity` action/class and starts it. It doesn't account for the fact that there may be multiple Activities defined in the Preferences XML referenced above. In fact, it doesn't account for a lot of error scenarios and can surely be optimized, but should serve as a decent proof of concept and starting point:

```
//somewhere in your app call this
//com.android.email works to open the email preferences on my Galaxy s4
startPreferenceActivity("com.android.email");

private void startPreferenceActivity(String type) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    AuthenticatorDescription[] descriptions = accountManager.getAuthenticatorTypes();
    AuthenticatorDescription neededDescription = null;
    for (AuthenticatorDescription description : descriptions) {
        if (description.type.contains(type)) {
            neededDescription = description;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (neededDescription != null) {
        String packageName = neededDescription.packageName;
        int prefsId = neededDescription.accountPreferencesId;
        try {
            Resources resources = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
            XmlResourceParser xpp = resources.getLayout(prefsId);
            xpp.next();
            String action = null;
            String targetPackage = packageName; //default to the account pref package name...?
            String targetClass = null;
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("intent")) {
                        int count = xpp.getAttributeCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            String name = xpp.getAttributeName(i);
                            if (name.equals("action")) {
                                action = xpp.getAttributeValue(i);
                            } else if (name.equals("targetPackage")) {
                                targetPackage = xpp.getAttributeValue(i);
                            } else if (name.equals("targetClass")) {
                                targetClass = xpp.getAttributeValue(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
            if (action != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(action));
            } else if (targetClass != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(createPackageContext(targetPackage, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY), Class.forName(targetClass)));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Sam, I kind of understand your approach, but I have tried your code with the different Authenticators on my device without any result, no preference got opened at all (I expected to open at least for `com.google.android.email` which I see as an Authenticator on my Nexus, but nothing appended...)

Comment: @LisaAnne have you stepped through the code to determine where it's failing?

Comment: Hi Sam, yes, it seems not to resolve the `action`, as `action` it gets some kind of code that seems not to be any `action`, and indeed it does not start any Activity

Comment: @LisaAnne, did you solve this problem,plz kindly tell me the result?

Answer (score 0):

You may have database of your accounts info u can open it and design a similar style form for it this can solve your problem